# Opening .html file with powershell using non-default browser

Tags: powershell

I am trying to open `.html` file with the help of powershell. I am using Yeoman and opening it with the command "Grunt Server" but it keeps opening it in default browser. Which command should I use to open it (for example) with Chrome?

I could change my default browser to Chrome but it is just interesting to know.

Answer (score 5):

You should try running `start chrome <your_filename_path>` from the command line.

Also if you know the Chrome path try opening via (for example):

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" <your_filename_path>`

Answer (score 1):

hello pals if you want to open a index.html file by firefox, run on power-shell.

`> c:\path/to/firefox.exe index.html`

example in my case

```
> 'c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' .\index.html
```